# Symmetry of Crystalline Lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, vectors, crystals, lattice-model

In the book [Solid State Physics by Kittel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKzL4.jpg), it is written in Bravais Lattice's definition that ***"the arrangement of atoms in the crystal looks the same when viewed from the point r as when viewed from every point r' translated by an integral multiple of the a’s"***, where $\vec{r}^{\prime}=\vec{r}+u_1 \vec{a}_1+u_2 \vec{a}_2+u_3 \vec{a}_3$. Can anyone please explain me the part in the given Lattice with pictures and vectos:
[image: Lattice]

Comment: _explain me the part in the given Lattice with pictures and vectos:_ That is unclear. Explain what part? Also, you should think about rewriting this so that there is a conceptual question.

Comment: Sir @josephh , I couldn't understand the quoted part **"the arrangement of atoms in the crystal looks the same when viewed from the point r as when viewed from every point r' translated by an integral multiple of the a’s"**. How does the arrangement look the same when viewed from different points?

Comment: I see. You may want to add that point to the question, though I see you have the answer you needed, which is good. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider you view under electron microscope crystal lattice area marked in yellow circle :
[image]

Now you move your microscope by a relative vector marked in red, namely by
$$ \delta \vec r  = -a_x \hat i - 2 a_y \hat j \tag 1$$

Does microscope see any differences in the lattice pattern after such move ? **No**.

In general, you can make as many as you like microscope movements of the form $$ \delta \vec r_{n,m} = n \cdot a_x \hat i + m \cdot a_y \hat j \tag 2$$

where $n,m \in [\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\ldots]$ and $a_x,a_y$ are [lattice constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_constant) along $x,y$ coordinate axis.

(as long as you are within crystal bounds), stop at $n_1,m_1$ take a picture, move to $n_2, m_2$, take a picture, and so on $N$ times. Then in  the end you will see that ALL your crystal lattice pictures achieved with electron microscope are **identical**.

This is what is meant by crystal atoms arrangement symmetry.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diagram to show the translation from position $A\,(\vec r)$ to position $B\,(\vec {r'})$.

[image]

In the illustrated example, $\vec {r'} = \vec r + 2\,\vec \alpha_1+1\,\vec \alpha_2+0\,\vec \alpha_3$

Comment: Sir @Farcher, I couldn't understand how does the arrangement look the same when viewed from different points? I understand the vector translation operation that you have illustrated, but how is the symmetry established?

Comment: If the dots were the positions of identical trees and you were place at position $A$ or position $B$ not knowing the actual position, could you, by just looking at the trees, decide where you were?

Comment: No sir. But can you please elaborate it further. It will be very illuminating for me. Thank you